# Transformations.map with ViewModel and LiveData in Androidx (issue)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive11/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/neube/smartdrive/controlamotores/SmartViewModel.kt

I have the above project, based on this:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_20.html

and I'm having this image issues:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_M3KBZnFXkX6I1dMNLejNZAAqrs_QBA9?usp=sharing

Can someone help?

Comment: I think I solved the problems in SmartViewModel class, but now I can not use the viewmodel in activity:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j-Et37f8dNc9dfVY1lccYw95vKDFBj1K?usp=sharing

updated:
https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive11/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/neube/smartdrive/MainActivity.kt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the wrong function type. it should be
androidx.arch.core.util.Function
and not 
import java.util.function.Function

In your Activity:
if your ViewModel is kotlin you should reference the livedata like hotStockViewModel.hotStockLiveData since it's a property.

On JVM the properties such as "hotStockLiveData" will have a "get HotStockLiveData" and "setHotStockLiveData" which from kotlin is called like hotStockViewModel.hotStockLiveData, but in JAVA you may use hotStockViewModel.getHotStockLiveData()
That's why you can't define a "getHotStockLiveData()" function in the viewModel.

Comment: the data is not being read, maybe the problem is in my data class/repository

updated:
https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive11/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/neube/smartdrive/MainActivity.kt

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x76RdtdZDT-O5kezpszr29UszFtUEleq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you don't get your data in the live data I would check the "FirebaseQueryLiveData" implementation, and try to add some logs there, to see if the data is delegated there.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lvRzroWt1BpKERceKAACM1Pd1NTbO5KX/view?usp=sharing
I have logic issue now. I can't change todoItem.PararUm (411) value, inside de While loop.

Look to SmartModel class and in my new updated project below:
https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive11/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/neube/smartdrive/MainActivity.kt

Comment: in the smartModel you declared them as val aka final, if you want to change them make them var.

Comment: Not Solved, tks

summarizing the issue/project: I turned the snapshot into a livedata, livedata that (according to the documentations) can only be used in Ui/OnCreate.

I will try kotlinx-coroutines-play-services, with await inside the while loop in MainActivity.kt.